# Get value and not [object Promise] from async function in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a function which is `async` and returns a value.

How do I get this value when I call that function within a React function component?
For me it always shows `[object Promise]`.
I already tried some stuff with the Effect Hook.

```
function Home() {
  const { publicKey } = useWallet();

  const [buttonClicked, setClick] = useState(false);
  let tokenAccounts;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (buttonClicked) {

      //This is the async function that I am calling
      tokenAccounts =  getTokenAccounts(publicKey); 

      console.log("token account: " + tokenAccounts);
      readyToShow = true;
    }
  })

  function handleButClick() {
    setClick(true);
  }

  let display;
  if (buttonClicked) {
    display = <div>test{tokenAccounts}</div>
  } else {
    display = (publicKey && <button onClick={handleButClick}>click</button>);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {display}
    </div>
  );
}
```

(It shows button and after the button is clicked it does show test and should also show the variable tokeAccounts which in my case is a `[object Promise]`)

Putting an `await` in front of the function call would be my intentional solution but then it says `Unexpected reserved word 'await'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const Home = () => {

    const { publicKey } = useWallet();
    const [tokenAccounts, setTokenAccounts] = useState(undefined);

    const handleButClick = () => {
        getTokenAccounts(publicKey)
        .then(result => setTokenAccounts(result));
        // Depending on API may need result.data or other
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {tokenAccounts === undefined && publicKey && 
                <button onClick={handleButClick}>click</button>
            }
            {tokenAccounts && <div>test{tokenAccounts}</div>}
        </React.Fragment>

    );
}
```

When the component first loads the tokenAccounts state variable is undefined so your button element will be displayed. When the button is clicked the event handler calls your async action and accesses the return value via the .then statement (also check out .catch and .finally). The tokenAccounts state variable is then set and the state change causes the component to refresh. Since tokenAccounts now has a value it is displayed and the button element hidden.

Comment: This did not work. Without .data it gave me an error and with it says undefined.
I added a log right after the call of the async function and also have some logs in the async function itself.
And the log here gets printed out before the async function logs, meaning that it did not wait for the result to get back and just loaded undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Home() {
  const { publicKey } = useWallet();

  const [buttonClicked, setClick] = useState(false);
  let tokenAccounts;

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTokenAccountsLocally = async () => {
      if (buttonClicked) {
        tokenAccounts = await getTokenAccounts(publicKey);
        console.log("token account: " + tokenAccounts);
      }
    }
    getTokenAccountsLocally();
  })

  function handleButClick() {
    setClick(true);
  }

  let display;
  if (buttonClicked) {

    //runs through this before tokenAccounts is loaded with the value
    display = <div>this is the {tokenAccounts}</div>

  } else {
    display = (publicKey && <button onClick={handleButClick}>click</button>);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {display}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Wrapping the async function call around another async function locally and then call it so I can add `wait` for the other async function call kind of works. `tokenAccounts` is now loaded with the returned value from the async function call. **BUT** it gets shown before it actually loaded the value.